Won't let me update
I get this message:
WARNING: You are trying to remove the following essential packages: libapt-pkg6.0 (due to apt) libgnutls30 (due to apt) libext2fs2 (due to e2fsprogs)

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

This question is similar to: Why does apt output "WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed." and prompt me to enter the full phrase when purging a package?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I am just initiating update and then after I provide my credentials it stops and presents this notice? I have no Idea why?

I get a prompt in my tool bar "a circle around a black arrow with a red dot, so I use my cursor to engage this prompt and my normal update window opens showing a list of all updates needed, when I engage update all, it asks for credentials then I enter them and it terminates the application with this message. I have had Linux since 2009 and am 64 and I haven't run into this before and I am not a programmer, just a grandma

This is on my PC and I have always just followed the prompts from the notification that updates were available

how do I ask my computer what system I'm using?

I found it UBUNTU 22.04.4 LTS  with LVFS
